# PHP code works when not put in a function

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch data and encode it to JSON. I have this very confusing trouble. The code I have put in getAnnotions() function, when I do not put it in function, the while loop (commented as //This loop) is reached. Whereas when I encapsulate the same code in getAnnotions() function, that while loop is not reached. What might be the problem?

Here is the code:

```
    <?php

$city=$_GET["city"];
//$limit="1";
//$place=$_GET["place"];

getAnnotions("1");

function getAnnotions($limit)
{

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","hidden","*******");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("merrycod_tummy", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deal where city_names LIKE '%".$city."%'");

    $rows = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {

          $rows[] = $row;


          $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT locationLat,locationLong FROM place where city ='".$city."' AND name='".$row['place_name']."' LIMIT ".$limit);



          while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
          {
                $rows[] = $row2;

              //This loop

          }


      }

      echo json_encode($rows);


    mysql_close($con);

}
 ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: http://nz.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php awwwwwwww, too late. But it's better to have 2 than 0 ;-)

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$city` is defined in the global scope, and in PHP functions variables of another scope cannot be used directly. You can either **pass it as a parameter (suggested)**, or use the [`global $city`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) at the beginning of your function.

Comment: I'd better rephrased it as "Because `$city` is in another scope", because the issue is related to scope, not to globals

Comment: @zerkms but it is still the "global scope"

Comment: yep, but for newbies it is better (imho) to know about general nature of the issue, not about its specific case

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to echo the sql in $result first,and then run the code you echo in phpmyadmin to look whether your sql is correct